# Deleted items of arraylist appear on listview when device mode changes from Landscape to portrait mode OR portrait to Landscape mode

Tags: android, arraylist

Hello friends, 
              As i am deleting the items of arrylist from listview than the item of arrylist become deleted but the problem occurs when i change the device mode from (Landscape to portrait mode ) OR  ( portrait to Landscape  mode ) than the deleted item becomes visible on the listview.Please help me to short from these problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: ARRAYLIST.REMOVE(POSITION) after this adapter.notifydatasechaged();

Comment: bro i used it but my main problem is that when i used the both modes of the device than the deleted items also shows in the listview

Comment: Item not removed in landscape mode? I am right

Comment: @stacktry Changes to the data are not persisted across orientation change. The change is happening only in memory and not to persistent storage (or whatever) from where the data comes :)

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha try my answer.surely your problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot all my dear friends for yours valuable comment....
I just change in the manifest file and it work fine for me..Again thanks friends..Below is the line which i have added in the manifest file along activity

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode
```

OR USE SIMPLY THESE

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time the underlying data for an adapter changes, you need to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on your adapter. It causes your `ListView` to be "refreshed".

[image]

**Update:**

> bro i used it but my main problem is that when i used the both modes
>   of the device than the deleted items also shows in the listview

It seems that you are reloading the same old data when the orientation changes. The changes do not persist. You need a mechanism whereby your changes to the underlying data will persist.

Answer (score 1):

For an ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged  works if you use the add(), insert(), remove(), and clear() on the Adapter.

```
arrayList.remove(position);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

when u update listview u use this methed on adapter object

```
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

When Activity goes to landscape, portrait mode activity is destroyed & it created again. I think in your activity's `onCreate()` method it reinitialized by your previous values. please check it.

If I am right then, you need to store the state of current arrays before activity is destroyed & restore it in `onCreate()` method.

This is sample code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      // get values from Bundle & set it to adapter
   }

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // save your state to Bundle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ravindra Kushwaha use follwing steps,

1. Store the **new arraylist** in **local db** or **shared preferences**.
2. If you delete an element immediately update the local db.
3. Always use arraylist from local db.

Answer (score 1):

On orientation change your arraylist is getting reinitialized or again getting back all the data from its source.

So when you are removing the data from arraylist, **Do remove it from the main source of the arraylist.**

As a result of this the arraylist will not get the removed data on orientation.

Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

P.S. Please mark this answer as correct if it helps.